# How do I unfocus UITextFields when user presses other controls/blank space?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITextField`. It works normally, meaning that when pressed, it fires `EditingDidBegin` method etc. The problem is that I cannot deselect it, meaning that the keyboard will be always visible, covering important controls. I thought that default behavior would be deselecting/hiding keyboard when user clicks somewhere different from the `UITextField`, for example on the empty space around it, but it's not - the `UITextField` is still there. One option to achieve this behavior would be adding touch listener to everything other than `UITextFields` and perform manual unfocusing when it fires, but that would be a terrible solution for obvious reasons.

> Question is, how do I unfocus `UITextFields` when user presses other controls/"blank space"?

**Proposed options don't work for Xamarin.iOS which is the one I need.**

Comment: You can add a transparent view on back of textfield and add tap gesture to view. When view is tapped dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: well what if I have buttons on the screen, they won't be pressed

Comment: To prevent Gesture on buttons or any other tappable controller use  `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I always add this to my ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // other stuff

    // but to stop editing when the user taps anywhere on the view, add this gesture recogniser
    let tapGestureBackground = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.backgroundTapped(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureBackground)
}

func backgroundTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    self.endEditing(true)   
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**SWIFT**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**Objective C**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

It will resign your textField or textView by tapping outside of it.

**Note: It will not affect on scrollView**

**Scroll View**

**Objective C**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;    
[yourScrollView/TableView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

-(void)hideKeyboard {
    [textFieldInYourScrollView/TableView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**SWIFT**

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

@objc func hideKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Hide Keyboard on Scrolling

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag       
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Comment: it resigns textview only when i press it again and not when i press outside of it

Comment: Do you have scrollView or just view? cause both methods are works like charm

Comment: no scrollviews. touchesBegan is fired only when i press inside the uitextfield itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

Create `UITapGestureRecognizer` object and add it to controller view. Write below code in `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

Don't forgot to extends your controller with `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

```
@interface YourViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField        *textField;

@end
```

Now implement delegate method `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;` its a delegate method of `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

In this method you can simply check for your textField (in this example we have used `self.textField`).

And write a condition to `resignFirstResponder` of your textField.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isEqual:self.textField]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyUIView : UIView
{
    //ctor..

    public override UIView HitTest(CGPoint point, UIEvent uievent)
    {
        var res = base.HitTest(point, uievent);

        if (res == null || !(res.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(UITextField)) || res.GetType() == typeof(UITextField)))
        {

            this.EndEditing(false);
        }  

        return res;
    }
}
```

in your ViewController

```
    public override void LoadView()
    {
        View = new MyUIView();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What' about calling the textField's `resignFirstResponder` when you want to unfocus it? That's the solution we're using in many Apps!

Answer (score 1):

If your using UITableViewCell you can hide your keyboard by setting one of these properties according to your requirement :-

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

And if your are using normal View of UIViewController you can simply add a UITapGestureRecognizer In viewDidLoad() :-

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideKeyBoard(sender:)))
```

And define it's action function inside your UIViewController, like that :-

```
func hideKeyBoard(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```